Implementation of Binary Cross Entropy gives not normal result
I'm trying to build a NN and just by the train stage im getting unnormal values of the loss function.. why is that?
oh and i can only use NumPy.
Thats how to data looks alike:
print(X_train.shape) #(784,800)
print(X_test.shape) #(784,200)
print(Y_train.shape) #(800,1)
print(Y_test.shape) #(200,1)

The Loss Function - BCE
def log_loss(y_hat, y):
    m = y.shape[0]
    epsilon = 1e-15 
    y_hat = np.clip(y_hat, epsilon, 1 - epsilon)  
    
    # loss = -1/m * (y * np.log(y_hat) + (1 - y) * np.log(1 - y_hat))
    loss = -1/m * (np.dot(y.T,np.log(y_hat)) + np.dot((1-y).T, np.log(1-y_hat)))
    return loss

Training stage - forward_prop + backprop
input_layer = X_train.shape[0]
hidden_layer = 128
learning_rate = 0.01
epochs = 10

W1 = np.random.randn(hidden_layer, input_layer)
b1 = np.zeros((hidden_layer, 1))
W2 = np.random.randn(1, hidden_layer)
b2 = np.zeros((1, 1))

X = X_train
Y = Y_train
loss_list = []
epoch_list = []
num_of_examples = X.shape[1]

for i in range(epochs):
  avg_epoch_loss = 0
  for j in range(num_of_examples):

    Z1 = np.matmul(W1,X[:,j].reshape(-1,1)) + b1 # DO NOT FORGET TO ADD THE BIAS
    A1 = sigmoid(Z1)
    Z2 = np.matmul(W2,A1) + b2
    A2 = sigmoid(Z2)
    Yout = Y[j]

    loss = log_loss( A2, Yout)
    avg_epoch_loss = avg_epoch_loss + loss

    dZ2 = (A2-Yout)
    dW2 = np.matmul(dZ2,A1.T)
    db2 = dZ2

    dA1 = np.matmul(W2.T,dZ2)
    dZ1 = dA1 * A1 * (1 - A1)
    dW1 = np.matmul(dZ1,X[:,j].reshape(-1,1).T)
    db1 = dZ1

    W2 = W2 - learning_rate * dW2
    b2 = b2 - learning_rate * db2
    W1 = W1 - learning_rate * dW1
   b1 = b1 - learning_rate * db1

  avg_epoch_loss = avg_epoch_loss/num_of_examples
  loss_list.append(avg_epoch_loss)
  epoch_list.append(i)
  print("Epoch", i," Loss:", avg_epoch_loss)

Those are the values that isn't normal - looking to values between 0-1 of course:
Epoch 0  Loss: [-18.37821485]
Epoch 1  Loss: [-18.82406892]
Epoch 2  Loss: [-18.82406892]
Epoch 3  Loss: [-19.99316345]
Epoch 4  Loss: [-29.91647793]
Epoch 5  Loss: [-32.32075724]
Epoch 6  Loss: [-32.89639034]
Epoch 7  Loss: [-32.34691639]
Epoch 8  Loss: [-32.749394]
Epoch 9  Loss: [-33.61631871]


As I said in the Staging Ground,  this is just because your labels are not 0/1 integer.
